# What is this iOS view called?

Tags: ios

When you click on a url from a native app such as the Twitter or Facebook app, a new panel comes up to display the page. When you X out the panel, you are still in the app at the location from where you launched the url. How is this done as opposed to launching the url in an instance of Safari ?

Comment: seems to be a UIWebView inside of a UIView

Comment: Excellent. Thanks much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/) or [SFSafariViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SafariServices/Reference/SFSafariViewController_Ref/)

`SFSafariViewController` is now widely used to *view* websites and it looks just like Safari.app (the user can access his saved passwords/cards, and he can use reader view), the problem is that you don't have any control over it.

`WKWebView` is a replacement for `UIWebView` and you will have a better control over it but you'll have to add your own navigation and refresh buttons and title bar.

Comment: If I need to add an access_token header, does it matter which of these web views to use. Is the setting of web headers easily done with all?

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView.  Here is a link to apples developer reference

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/

Comment: Excellent. Thanks much!

Comment: @codezoo if you want to support iOS 8 and higher only see Bader Al-Rasheed's answer